# Did all cats used to be feminine?

Tags: archaicisms

I have always believed --- from somewhere --- that in archaic English, cats were always referred to using feminine pronouns, regardless of what sex they actually were. But I thought to go and find a reference for it and I can't find anything.

Was this ever a real thing, or was I just hallucinating?

Comment: [Why People Think of All Dogs as Male and All Cats as Female](https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/blog/canine-corner/202201/why-people-think-all-dogs-male-and-all-cats-female).

Comment: 'I thought to go and find a reference for it': the 'think to Vinf' construction, less of a negative polarity item than it once was.

Comment: I thought I remembered an earlier thread about this, but I can't find it.  I  commented that I had read somewhere that the Victorians maintained a polite fiction that dogs were male and cats female (to avoid anything so indelicate as looking to see which an individual was), but could not find any references.

Comment: Are you speculating or you've read somewhere? Also, do you mean obsolete usage instead of archaic? Do we include Old English? For example, in Old English, nouns had a grammatical gender (just like German today) and animal names had a grammatical gender too. However, there were two versions of "cat" in Old English: _cat_ or _catt_ (masculine), _catte_ (feminine).

Comment: It's also notable that in French, "chat" is masculine.

Comment: @StuartF I knew of a primary school teacher who taught that "toads are male frogs".

Comment: Whorf mentions it as a case of covert gender agreement. As the owner of a female dog and later a male cat I can testify that people do use _he/him/his_ for dogs and _she/her/hers_ for cats, unless they're intimate enough to know the actual gender.

Comment: @ermanen I'm thinking more recently that Old English, more 1700s or 1800s. I could swear that I saw an actual reference _somewhere_, but I don't remember where. Kate Bunting reports the same thing.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm Scottish, which means I get a whole pile of extra grammatical weirdness on top of what British English already has!

Comment: It's used a lot in the church I'm part of: "I thought to go over and see X" /  "I thought to speak on the need to see God ruling even when world events appear to go from bad to worse." ...  Fifty years ago, I'd only have found "I just didn't think to go over and see X" grammatical.